# REST API Authentication stateless

Tags: rest, api, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt

Can someone please tell me which of this architectures is stateful/stateless?

1. REST API with session user authentication stored on redis.
2. REST API with JWT user authentication stored with revocation list on redis.
3. REST API with oauth2 user authentication.

I would like to also know if I can have resource and authorization server as one and the same API in terms of oauth2. Is it worth to have own authorization server?

What kind of user authentication and app authentication would be easy and secure to use as start up for REST API that will be used by the website and mobile app? I understand it would be 2 authentications one for user and one for app.

Please this is for me more like wrap up of all stuff I've read so I just need short answers - already had a lot of reading.

Comment: Stateless means you don't keep a state between 2 server calls. If you have a user session, whatever the storage system, then you have a state.

Comment: thanks for the answer, does it mean 2nd scenario is stateful as well? This essentially stores user state on the blacklist.

Comment: The 2nd scenario is stateless as you don't have any session and you will check the token to verify the caller credentials. From my POV, the 3rd scenario is the way to go. But keep in mind that OAuth2 is not designed to user authentication, but allows your API to accept requests from a client (e.g. web app) that received a delegation from the owner of the resource (e.g. a user)

Answer (score 1):

The key goal is to externalise it - your UI and API code is then simple and stateless. This is what an Authorization Server enables.

The AS is something you interface with and configure - but you don't code it yourself.

Use a free / cheap Authorization Server from a cloud provider like Google or AWS

Following the OAuth 2.0 and Open Id Connect standards is the lowest cost option if you make the right choices - though there is a learning curve.

As an example my [Cloud Samples](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart) are pretty much zero cost to me - and my code is simple - even though anyone on the internet can run them.

In terms of getting connected, maybe have a browse of my [first tutorial](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/25/basicspa-execution/).

Comment: does it mean that if I use cookie/session authentication and externalise sessions to store them on redis this is stateless?